# Want to iterate from A to ZZ column in excel through python

Tags: python

I have code which iterate from A TO Z but I want to iterate from A to ZZ , how can I modify this code to iterate till column ZZ

```
import pandas
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.worksheet.table import Table
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
from string import ascii_uppercase as i


book = load_workbook('QualityReview Business-Template.xlsx')

writer = pandas.ExcelWriter('QualityReview Business-Template.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') 
writer.book = book
busi_issue_date.to_excel(writer, "IssueData")
worksheet = book["IssueData"]

for letter in i:   
    max_width= 0

    for row_number in range(1,worksheet.max_row +1):
        if len(str(worksheet[f'{letter}{row_number}'].value)) > max_width:
            max_width = len(str(worksheet[f'{letter}{row_number}'].value))
            worksheet.column_dimensions[letter].width = max_width + 1
        

writer.save()
```

Comment: You can also index the columns by number, you don't need the names...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use itertools:

```
from string import ascii_uppercase as i
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

seq = list(i)+ [x[0]+x[1] for x in combinations_with_replacement(i, 2)]

for letters in seq:
    # do whatever
```

which gives the sequence of string A, B ... Z, AA, AB ... ZZ

Answer (score 0):

Using the alphabet you have imported as `i`, you can generate the letter pairs using two generators:

```
double_letters = (l1+l2 for l1 in i for l2 in i)
```

This generator will yield the strings 'AA', 'AB' ... 'ZY', 'ZZ'.

You can then chain this iterable with the single-letter alphabet you have, using itertools, and replace your outer for loop with this:

```
for letter in itertools.chain(i, double_letters):
```

Don't forget to `import itertools` for that.

This will then yield the strings 'A' ... 'Z', 'AA', 'AB' ... 'ZY', 'ZZ' in the `letter` variable.